# Powershell - keep ID only in filename

Tags: windows, powershell, file

I have a big folder with other folders and files in it, and I would like to keep only a code between [] of the filename for a certain file type. Here's an example:

Title [ID].txt

All files are like that. I'd like all the txt files to get just the ID as name. I think powershell can help me but I don't know how.

Any help please ?

Too noob in PS to be able to do anything without risking to mess all up

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following a try, first use `Get-ChildItem` to find any file or folder containing `[` and `]` in their name, then you can pipe that object to `Rename-Item` where you can use a regex pattern to extract what's within the brackets to use as the "new name" for the file or folder. The `-WhatIf` switch will inform you about the operation that would be performed, you should remove it after confirming the code will do what you expect it to do.

```bash
Get-ChildItem path\to\sourceFolder -Filter '*[*]*' -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {
    [regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=\[)[^]]+').Value + $_.Extension
} -WhatIf
```

If you want to target only files and not folders then you can include the `-File` switch:

```bash
Get-ChildItem path\to\sourceFolder -Filter '*[*]*' -Recurse -File | ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! It is great, but I'd like only the files to change names, not the folders

Comment: Alright, and how can I do it ? What would the file look like ? Sorry I really don't know powershell really well. I tried pasting it in a bat file but it does not work